# Add series of values to another variable for each value of a variable

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to construct a dataset using month and a product ID. Each unique product ID is stored in Table1 and all the months in question are stored in Table2.

```
Table1 
1234
1254


Table2 
Jan2010
Feb2010
Mar2010
Apr2010
```

The final data would look something like this:

```
ID   Date 
1234 Jan2010
1234 Feb2010
1234 Mar2010
1234 Apr2010
1254 Jan2010
1254 Feb2010
1254 Mar2010
1254 Apr2010
```

How might I merge these two tables to get the result?

Comment: select * from table1,table2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table2.Date
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
ORDER BY Table1.Id ASC, Table2.Date ASC
```

Comment: Answers that are only code are discouraged on Stack Overflow.  Please add some english explanation of what you're suggesting to answer the question, particularly as to how/why the code does what it does, so the OP can learn the hows and whys rather than just the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Prior `proc sql`solution works. However, if you are working with huge dataset, that environment is not always feasible. I've used more 'sas'-y solution:

```
data Table1 ; 
input num; cards;
1234
1254 
; run;

data Table2;
input dates $ ; cards;
Jan2010
Feb2010
Mar2010
Apr2010
; run;

data all_comb;
    set table1; 
        do i=1 to n;
            set table2 point=i nobs=n; 
            output; 
        end; 
run;
```

But seriously, use Proc sql if it is an option.

Comment: Consider loading TABLE2 into memory with SASFILE statement.

Comment: @data_null_ Interesting. Found the basics about this. Could you reference a good practical source to read more about this?